# Unable to get the current item properties inside my Remote Event Receiver. I got the After and Before only

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, remote-event-receiver, item-updating

I have the following code inside my remote event receiver:

```
  public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
          var currenttitle = properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["Title"];
```

But inside the `properties.ItemEventProperties` it does not have a method to retrieve the current properties, where i only got the Before and After properties as follow:

[image]

So when updating an item, I should get the before, current and after properties for the item, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, `properties.ItemEventProperties` doesn't have the current item. but it has the listid and itemid, so using that we can fetch it from the list and use it.

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
{
    if(clientContext != null)
    {
        List requestList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListId);
        ListItem item = requestList.GetItemById(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId);
        clientContext.Load(item);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        item["Your column Name"] //this will have the current item value
        item.Update();
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();                        
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i know i can get the item by id, but this mean extra request to the server, i was trying to find a way to get the properties directly... but seems it is not available..

Comment: yes, as per the Microsoft documentation, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj171628%28v%3doffice.15%29,  SPRemoteEventProperties.ItemEventProperties doesn't have the current item